# Third level navigation items going off screen and not wrapping

Tags: navigation, word-wrap

Here is the website: https://trovarebusinesssolutions.com

If you look under Solutions and hover on Customer Relationship Management the submenu (MS Dynamics CRM) will fly out off the screen (depending on screen size). Is there any way to get this to fly out the other way, stay on the screen, drop down below, or something else?

I am using Wordpress 4.1 with the Impreza theme.

I was thinking of limiting the width to 125px on all secondary menus and having the words wrap but I can't seem to get it to work:
CSS:

```
.l-header .w-nav-list.level_2, .l-header .w-nav-list.level_3, .l-header .w-nav-list.level_4 {
    background-color: #1a3869;
    max-width: 125px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children has_sublevel w-nav-item level_1 menu-item-48 togglable"><a class="w-nav-anchor level_1" href="https://trovarebusinesssolutions.com/solutions/"><span class="w-nav-title">Solutions</span><span class="w-nav-arrow"></span></a>
<ul class="w-nav-list level_2" style="opacity: 0; display: none;">
    <li id="menu-item-94" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has_sublevel w-nav-item level_2 menu-item-94 togglable"><a class="w-nav-anchor level_2" href="https://trovarebusinesssolutions.com/solutions/microsoft-dynamics-crm/"><span class="w-nav-title">Customer Relationship Management</span><span class="w-nav-arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="w-nav-list level_3" style="opacity: 0; display: none;">
        <li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page w-nav-item level_3 menu-item-33"><a class="w-nav-anchor level_3" href="https://trovarebusinesssolutions.com/solutions/microsoft-dynamics-crm/"><span class="w-nav-title">Microsoft Dynamics CRM</span><span class="w-nav-arrow"></span></a>       </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-95" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has_sublevel w-nav-item level_2 menu-item-95 togglable"><a class="w-nav-anchor level_2" href="https://trovarebusinesssolutions.com/solutions/click-dimensions/"><span class="w-nav-title">Marketing Automation</span><span class="w-nav-arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="w-nav-list level_3" style="opacity: 0; display: none;">
        <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page w-nav-item level_3 menu-item-49"><a class="w-nav-anchor level_3" href="https://trovarebusinesssolutions.com/solutions/click-dimensions/"><span class="w-nav-title">Click Dimensions</span><span class="w-nav-arrow"></span></a>       </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer answered this for me on their site. They have a css class .drop-left to make the menu go the other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the width:

```
.level_2, .level_3 {
    max-width: 125px;
}
```